# MySql SELECT 2 cells into one column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table:

```
player_id file_1 file_2
```

For example:

```
1 test1.jpg test2.jpg
2 test3.jpg 
3 test4.jpg
4 test5.jpg test6.jpg
```

I need to get output like this

```
1 test1.jpg
1 test2.jpg
2 test3.jpg
3 test4.jpg
4 test5.jpg
4 test6.jpg
```

I need to use LIMIT and OFFSET to this. Is it possible to achieve this with one sql query?

Comment: Seems like a bad design in the first place.

Comment: You mean bad table structure? It`s true but it doesn't depend on me and unfortunately i can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union two queries to return one result set:

```
SELECT player_id, file_1 file FROM table WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT player_id, file_2 FROM table WHERE ...
```

Comment: I don't believe... Its work great, Thank You "master" :) How can i miss that :(